# Good tablet for Linux?

Tags: linux, tablet

Just curious, any suggestions for tablets that run Linux well? There doesn't seem to be much information out there about this, but from my research a few that work well are:

- Samsung Slate 7
- Acer Iconia W4
- Cube i7 Stylus

Anyone know of any others or any resources to help me find a good Linux tablet?

My budget is $200 - $300

Comment: Could you explain what exactly you're looking for besides a Linux tablet? What screen size, screen type, buttons, or other features are you wanting?

Comment: Android is a sort-of Linux! What distribution do you want to run? IIRC, some tablets are sold with some version of Ubuntu

Comment: I'm not too picky in this case, I really just want something with 10.6"-ish screen size (a little smaller works though) and the ability to run a Linux desktop distro well.

Answer (score 2):

Some time ago I've successfully installed Linux (ROSA R3) on the similar [Acer ICONIA Tab W500](http://linux-hardware.org/index.php?computer=4c-72-b9-1a-26-df).

Currently there are Linux installations on 3 different ICONIA Tab W500, W501, W501P and W700 in the database. And there are no any information for other tablets you listed. So I can recommend you the Acer tablet.

However please don't expect that all Linux applications will support touchscreen interface. Most of the time you will work with your Linux tablet as a traditional laptop via the keyboard and mouse.